# How can i render webform on custom url with custom html in drupal 8

Tags: theming, 8, webforms, page-controller

Basically I am using sample code which shown in below.

public function test(){

```
$webform = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->load('contact_us');
$webform = $webform->getSubmissionForm();
$dd= drupal_render($webform);

return array(
'#type'=> 'markup',
'#markup' => $dd.'<div><p>test</p></div>'

);

}
```

I'm using return type markup then form is not rendering properly.So any help available. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Btw. You should use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` instead of deprecated `drupal_render()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you `return $webform;` without rendering. Or use the webform render element, then you don't need to load the form:

```
return [
  'test1' => ['#markup' => '<div><p>test1</p></div>'],
  'form' => [
    '#type' => 'webform',
    '#webform' => 'webform_id',
  ],
  'test2' => ['#markup' => '<div><p>test2</p></div>'],
];
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me the solution but  i also want return type #markup because I also want to render custom html with webform So if any help available thank you in advance.

Comment: You can return as many render children as you want, see the edit. But don't render early in a D8 controller.